# GraphDB free does not run on Windows 10

Tags: execution, graphdb

I have tried to install GraphDB free 9.0.0 on a Windows 10 laptop (x64). The installation finishes succesfully but when I double click GraphDB it does not run. What should I check in order to fiind out why it does not run?
Thank you

Comment: Are you running the native application (exe) or the standalone server (zip)? One possible cause for the problem is if you don't have java installed.

Answer (score 0):

I install GDB regularly on Windows 10 using the installer (eg GraphDB_Free-9.3.0.exe). It comes bundled with Java. Here's the version:

```
cd C:\Users\vladimir.alexiev.000\AppData\Local\GraphDB Free\runtime\bin
java --version
openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.7+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.7+10, mixed mode)
```

It's convenient because after starting, it opens Workbench in your browser, and a small control panel where you can see the log etc, and a tray icon.

If you use one of the other distributions, check your Java version.